# FFMPEG filter_complex overlays work well on windows but generates error on Linux and OSX

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video-encoding, ffmpeg-filters

So, I am applying multiple overlays on a video using FFMPEG, on windows it always works fine for every size and number of overlays, but in case of MAC or Linux, it generates error for reinitializing filters.

Let's say I have a video of 190MB, and about 182 overlay PNGs which will be overlayed using filter_complex.

```
   for (let i = 0; i < pngPaths.length; i++) {
    const start = Number(transcriptions[i].start).toFixed(2);
    const end = Number(transcriptions[i].end).toFixed(2);
    const overlayX = '0';
    const overlayY = `0`;
    filterComplex += `[${
      i + 1
    }:v] overlay=${overlayX}:${overlayY}:enable='between(t,${start},${end})'`;
    if (i < pngPaths.length - 1) {
      filterComplex += '[vout];[vout]';
    }
  }
```

I am creating a filter_complex using above function.

And then running FFMPEG command like this:

```
  const outputPath =
  path.join(__dirname, '..') +
  `/projects/${project.originalVideoFile}-output.mp4`;
this.appGateway.sendProgress(JSON.stringify(userId), 'progress', 0);
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const ffmpegCommand = ffmpeg();

  // Add video input
  ffmpegCommand.input(videoPath);

  // Add PNG inputs
  for (const pngPath of pngPaths) {
    ffmpegCommand.input(pngPath);
  }
  if (project?.user?.subscription?.plan?.id === 1) {
    ffmpegCommand.input('watermark.png');
  }
  ffmpegCommand
    .complexFilter(filterComplex)
    .outputOptions('-c:v', 'libx264')
    .output(outputPath)
    .on('progress', (progress) => {
      this.appGateway.sendProgress(
        JSON.stringify(userId),
        'progress',
        Math.round(progress.percent),
      );
    })
    .on('end', async () => {
```

"You can ignore the socket emmisions"

This works will on windows. But when processing on OSX or Linux, it gives the following error:

```
  Stream #95:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #96:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #97:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #98:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #99:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #100:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #101:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #102:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #103:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #104:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #105:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #106:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #107:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #108:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #109:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #110:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #111:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #112:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #113:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #114:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #115:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #116:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #117:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #118:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #119:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #120:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #121:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #122:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #123:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #124:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #125:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #126:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #127:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #128:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #129:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #130:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #131:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #132:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #133:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #134:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #135:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #136:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #137:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #138:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #139:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #140:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #141:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #142:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #143:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #144:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #145:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #146:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #147:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #148:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #149:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #150:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #151:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #152:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #153:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #154:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #155:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #156:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #157:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #158:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #159:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #160:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #161:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #162:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #163:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #164:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #165:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #166:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #167:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #168:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #169:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #170:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #171:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #172:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #173:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #174:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #175:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #176:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #177:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #178:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #179:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #180:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #181:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #182:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
  overlay:default (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[auto_scale_47 @ 0x60000182bbd0] Failed to configure output pad on auto_scale_47
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Resource temporarily unavailable
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #182:0
[aac @ 0x13c063f40] Qavg: 325.486
[aac @ 0x13c063f40] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
Conversion failed!


/Users/surajkadam/Desktop/12/subtitleo-server/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/processor.js:182
          handleExit(new Error('ffmpeg exited with code ' + code));
                     ^
Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: Conversion failed!

    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/surajkadam/Desktop/12/subtitleo-server/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/processor.js:182:22)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
```

Comment: What are the ffmpeg versions on the three systems?

Comment: @Gyan , The FFMPEG version on my Linux machine is not directly checkable as we weren't able to log into the CLI. But I looked into the build logs of the Docker image and  got the version it's fetching from there, which was `amd 64 7:4.3.6-0+deb11u1`. But I also checked in my MAC device, it had latest FFMPEG 6.0_1, but there I am still getting the same error. On my windows, the version is: `ffmpeg version 2023-09-07-git-9c9f48e7f2-full_build-www.gyan.dev`, is there a difference? If yes, what can I do to fix this on my MAC and Linux devices? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, the root error msg is `Error while processing the decoded data for stream #182:0`; remove that input and check else it could be a memory or process or permissions constraint.

Comment: @Gyan I am generating inputs dynamically using node-canvas, those are typically same (i.e a PNG). This is how we are generating PNG from a canvas: `const buffer = canvas.toBuffer('image/png');` , so as for other videos its parsing only foe heavy videos, like the one I am using, it's giving the error. It also says `Failed to configure output pad on auto_scale_47
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Resource temporarily unavailable`. It maybe a permission or limit issue? How can I allow FFMPEG to use all permissions? in MAC and Linux.

Comment: @Gyan, also, it is working fine on Windows, if it was an issue with input, I am not getting it in my windows. Is this OS specific?

Comment: @Gyan, hi sir any update regarding this? we are really stuck here..